# How to find destroyed data rows using audit trail with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, audit-trail, data-loss

I am using an audit table to find what records a single destructive SQL statement that was run on say '2011-01-01 08:00:00.000'. You can assume that each MyTable record only got updated once on this day the script ran. This SQL was probably run by a user and can not be retrieved. Everytime there is a change to MyTable an audit trail of the new value gets stored in AuditMyTable.

My original table schema:

```
MyTable(AccountId int PK, Amount int)
```

My audit trail table for MyTable schema:

```
AuditMyTable(AccountId int, Amount int, AuditDate datetime)
```

**My question is how do I write a SQL join from AuditMyTable against itself so that I can get back the following data:**

`AuditMyTable.AccountId, AuditMyTable.Amount as [NullAmount], AuditMyTablePrevious.Amount as [PreviousNotNullAmount]`

Comment: You are only interested in one specific record at a known time or the whole table?

Comment: Essentially, trying to discover a list of record PKs which had a value before the time the SQL ran and then were made null at the time it ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to get your sequence (I'm making one from your dates, assuming they are strictly increasing):

```
SELECT AccountId, cur.AuditDate AS cur_AuditDate, MAX(prev.AuditDate) AS prev_AuditDate
FROM AuditMyTable AS cur
LEFT JOIN AuditMyTable AS prev
    ON prev.AccountId = cur.AccountId
    AND prev.AuditDate < cur.AuditDate
GROUP BY AccountId, cur.AuditDate
```

Then use it:

```
WITH Ordering AS (
    SELECT AccountId, cur.AuditDate AS cur_AuditDate, MAX(prev.AuditDate) AS prev_AuditDate
    FROM AuditMyTable AS cur
    LEFT JOIN AuditMyTable AS prev
        ON prev.AccountId = cur.AccountId
        AND prev.AuditDate < cur.AuditDate
    GROUP BY AccountId, cur.AuditDate
)
SELECT cur.AccountId, cur.Amount as [NullAmount], prev.Amount as [PreviousNotNullAmount]
FROM AuditMyTable AS cur
INNER JOIN Ordering
    ON Ordering.AccountId = cur.AccountId
    AND Ordering.cur_AuditDate = cur.Audit_Date
LEFT JOIN AuditMyTable AS prev
    ON prev.AccountId = cur.AccountId
    AND prev.Audit_Date = Ordering.prev_AuditDate
```